# how can apply multiple normalizations on columns in pandas dataframe between different range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

I want to apply normalization on multiple columns in Pandas dataframe by using for-loop under the condition of below:

Normalization for A , B columns between : **[-1 , +1]**

Normalization for C column between      : **[-40 , +150]**

and replace results in dataframe and store it as csv file.

my data is txt file is following:

```
id_set: 000
     A: 3.29117131
     B: -3.68965849
     C: 345.9876546
```

I already defined `normalize` function and call it after `if` clause and `else` clause and print them for controlling it works but in the end I can't find out how can I replace the result as new_value in new dataframe which is called `df_norm`.

```
def normalize(value, min_value, max_value, min_norm, max_norm):
    new_value = ((max_norm - min_norm)*((value - min_value)/(max_value - min_value))) + min_norm
    return new_value

#Split data in three different lists A, B and C
dff = pd.read_csv('D:\me4.TXT', header=None)
id_set = dff[dff.index % 4 == 0].astype('int').values
A = dff[dff.index % 4 == 1].values
B = dff[dff.index % 4 == 2].values
C = dff[dff.index % 4 == 3].values

#df contains all the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C'], index = id_set[:,0])  
data = {'A': A[:,0], 'B': B[:,0],'C': C[:,0]}

#next iteration create all plots, change the number of cycles
for i in df:
    min_val = df[i].min()
    max_val = df[i].max()
    if 'C' in i:
        #Applying normalization for C between [-40,+150]
        new_value = normalize(df[i].values, min_val, max_val, -40, 150)
    else:
        #Applying normalization for A , B between [-1,+1]
        new_value = normalize(df[i].values, min_val, max_val, -1, 1)

df_norm = pd.df(new_value)
#df_norm = df[i].new_value()
print(df_norm)
df_norm.to_csv('df_norm.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

my desired output should be:

```
           A         B           C
000   -0.716746  0.158663  112.403310
010   -0.726023  0.037448  113.289702
020   -0.716746  0.165824  112.567557
030   -0.726040 -0.104426  150.000000
040   -0.693538  0.208556  112.372881
050   -0.104061  0.158573  112.176238
060   -0.735354  0.144351  112.148590
070   -0.712112  0.151505  111.973514
080   -0.336932  0.215719  113.076807
090   -0.698181  0.130189  111.839319
010    0.068357 -0.019388  114.346421
011    0.022007  0.165824  112.381444
```

later I want to develop this normalization bu apply Gaussian function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing one column at a time:

```
for i in main_data:
    min_val = df[i].min()
    max_val = df[i].max()
    if 'C' in i:
        #Applying normalization for C between [-40,+150]
        new_value = normalize(df[i].values, min_val, max_val, -40, 150)
    else:
        #Applying normalization for A , B between [-1,+1]
        new_value = normalize(df[i].values, min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
    df_norm[i] = new_value 

# df_norm = pd.df(new_value)
```

Comment: When I use `df_norm[i] = new_value` just gives me result of column `C`. Aim is to have normalization of All columns `A`,`B` ,`C` together. Any ideas?

Comment: man would u do me a favor and have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489201/how-can-make-a-dataset-of-elements-of-matrices-in-dataframe) You might have an idea?